# Running selenium hub in maven

Tags: maven, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to run selenium server using role hub in maven using selenium-maven-plugin in order to use phantomjs driver from remote control test, so far my plugin configuration is very straightforward:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>start-selenium</id>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>start-server</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <background>true</background>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
      <id>stop-seleniump</id>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>stop-server</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>  
</plugin>
```

Then I hook phantomjs using maven execution plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>phantomjs</executable>
    <arguments>
      <argument>--webdriver=8080</argument>
      <argument>--webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444</argument>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With this configuration the output is: `HTTP ERROR: 403 Forbidden for Proxy` and I can't go any further. Anyone has successfully configured this?

Comment: I decided took a different approach in order to run the selenium test using phantomjs. But it would be really cool if someone can answer this question as I think it might be a more efficient an elegant way of dealing with the integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be too much of a stretch to just create a script that uses YAJSW (Yet Another Java Service Wrapper) to accommodate registering the grid hub as a service.  Then, Maven can call the script and start it as its own separate process.  Also, Maven could call a stop service to stop it.  I think it would be elegant.

[Here is my almost working attempt](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5696040).  I'll need to solicit help from a Selenium expert to get it working.  Having a error when registering service that is unexpected.  Most of the work is done though.  Once I get this working, it will be good to go for you.

Now, while you could run the Grid Hub as a service, you wouldn't want to do the same to the Node because it needs access to the desktop (and services can only access their own invisible private desktop).  So, perhaps that brings us back to the same problem that you are trying to solve.